# Splitting IF/ELSE statement between two php tags, gives Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

Tags: php, session, include, if-statement

I have built a PHP login system which starts session before loading each page and checks if the user is logged in.

On my Protected page I have a include at the top that starts the session and the if statement as to load the page or not. And then a the bottom I have another include which is the else statement redirecting back to the login page. This works fine when in the page direct, but when included from elsewhere I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

This is the code

Include 1:

```
<?php

session_start();

if ($_SESSION['username'])
{
?>
```

*THIS IS THE PROTECTED CONTENT THAT GETS LOADED IF SESSION EXISTS*

Include 2:

```
<?php
}
else
header ("location: index.php");

?>
```

I think this might be caused by splitting the curly braces on the statement into two PHP tags, the reason why I have done this is to load a whole page if the if statement is true, rather than leaving it in PHP and echoing each line of HTML seperate.

How can I resolve this? or is there a better way for me to split the IF/ELSE statement.

Thanks
Danny

Comment: I don't believe splitting curly brackets in multiple tags work when opening and closing them in 2 different files. Wouldn't it be better to do something like: `if($_SESSION['username']) { /*include protected content*/ }`

Comment: @bluegman991 Thanks, How could I include the whole of the protected page without echoing each line of HTML? and without making the file accessible without starting a session.

Comment: Put the protected page in a seperate file (possibly in a protected directory), then inside the if statement include the protected file.

Comment: @bluegman991 the only problem with doing that is that the login system is been used for a booking system, so the includes would be appearing in many pages not just one file that needs protecting.

Answer (score 1):

Opening and closing curly brackets in between files is currently not possible. If you attempt to do this it will result in an "unexpected $end" syntax error.

I'm not sure what exactly you are shooting for but based on your comments you should be doing something like the following.

You should have 1 file you can name it whatever, but i'm just going to call it "allProtectedContent.php"

You said that there would be multiple files that need to be protected (which by that I assume you mean: multiple php files that need to be executed if the session exists). So inside of allProtectedContent.php you can include all the file files that you want to be executed/output.

Then in your main file you should simply have this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    include 'allProtectedContent.php';
}
else
{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
```

So then anything you put in allProtectedContent.php will only be executed/output if the username key in $_SESSION is set.

Example of allProtectedContent.php:

```
<?php
// verify session
// echo some stuff
// include more files
// execute some functions
// run any php code you want
?>
```

Comment: Sorry my previous comment didnt seem to work.
There are many pages to the system such as new_booking.php edit_booking.php search_results.php etc. And I want all these to be checked for session before loading. It would be a pain to have all these files have a separate page and then include them in. So if possible I would want to do this without including the page.

Comment: So basically you're trying to check if the session variable exist, in as many files as possible, with as little text as possible.

Comment: @DannyGreen  Well since you don't want the page to be included the only other way to do this is by going through and editing each file and including a file with this code `if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { header('Location: index.php'); exit; }` or by putting that code in each file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your HTML carefully and look for a mistyped `?>` where you intended a `/>`.

Comment: I get the same issue even if I put a simple paragraph tag in the protected area, so don't think this is been caused by the protected content.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using curly braces, you may try using the colon notation as seen below.

```
<?php

session_start();

if ($_SESSION['username']):
?>

...

<?php else: header("location: index.php"); endif;
```

Comment: Yeah, still wont work :/ getting same error. This is annoying, the system works fine until I take it out of the protected page and put it into includes.